# Java - Spintax , what should i do?

Tags: java, spintax

I just wrote my program in C# but I want rewrite it in Java. I want create spintax text.

My C# code:

```
        static string spintax(Random rnd, string str)
    {

            // Loop over string until all patterns exhausted.
            string pattern = "{[^{}]*}";
            Match m = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                // Get random choice and replace pattern match.
                string seg = str.Substring(m.Index + 1, m.Length - 2);
                string[] choices = seg.Split('|');
                str = str.Substring(0, m.Index) + choices[rnd.Next(choices.Length)] + str.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
                m = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            }

            // Return the modified string.
            return str;

    }
```

I've Updated My Code to

```
static String Spintax(Random rnd,String str)
{
    String pat = "\\{[^{}]*\\}";
    Pattern ma; 
    ma = Pattern.compile(pat);
    Matcher mat = ma.matcher(str);
    while(mat.find())
    {
        String segono = str.substring(mat.start() + 1,mat.end() - 1);
        String[] choies = segono.split("\\|",-1);
        str = str.substring(0, mat.start()) + choies[rnd.nextInt(choies.length)].toString() + str.substring(mat.start()+mat.group().length());
        mat = ma.matcher(str);
    }
    return str;
}
```

works like a charm :D thanks all for your support..

Comment: From wikipedia: Most uses of spun content are considered a black hat SEO spam practice. This is because most spun content is produced through automated methods and is considered human unreadable. Such content is only usable for mass posting on non-editorial sites purely for SEO; by definition, spam.

Comment: my client ask that feature :(

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to mention that :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets

```
 String pat = "\\{[^{}]*\\}";
```

Comment: You still get the same problem?? That should have taken care of the illegal repetition. Maybe the problem has moved on?